# what is the fastest sensor sampling frequency of Android Google Pixel 6a?

Tags: android

I'm currently using SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST to read the accelerometer data, and it shows that the sampling frequency is 440 Hz. Is 440 Hz the maximum sampling frequency for sensors on the Google Pixel 6a? How might I increase it to 500 Hz?

Comment: This might be the fused data rate. You might want to take a look at the raw data? Also, the data rate is usually set in the BSP itself.

Comment: I tried to use Android native code to access the hardware. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78215083/andriod-phone-accelerometer-reading-native-code-vs-android-api